# Command line tool to interpret HTML/CSS and get element styles

Tags: html, css, linux, command-line, interpreter

Let's say I download an html page along with all its css files (e.g. with curl)
So I have some html code, some css in head, in tags, and some css from files.

Is there a tool I can use to, e.g. get the color and font-size of that character at position 2957 in page, or the height of this tag starting at position 3917?

I am looking for either Linux command line without X, or perl modules.
Of course the tool would know how proprieties come from parents, get overwritten by css codes depending on their order, etc.

Thanks!

EDIT: height was a dangerous example that can confuse the reader. I do not mean the rendered height when auto e.g. I meant the string "auto". So no rendering necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard headless browser is PhantomJS: http://phantomjs.org/ (and there are other similar ones like https://slimerjs.org/).

I'm not sure how pixel-perfect it's going to be (but that's true even with different versions of desktop browsers on a mix of OSs etc.), but would do the full DOM and CSS parsing that you can script and get results from.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking for browser that can work without any graphic subsystem. Just to measure some element ( "height of this tag starting at position 3917" ) you need fonts on that machine and code that does rasterization of fonts.

I don't think that anyone from browser vendors even looking in rendering-on-headless-device direction.

So is the answer: almost no chances to find such a tool.

Comment: Answers like this from @c-smile make me realize SO rep is all but worthless. I don't blame the OP for asking the question (they have a problem they are trying to solve), but if one is a self-described "expert" in HTML, I would think they would be able to provide a more helpful answer or at least ask a follow-up question instead of an answer. (Or knowing the concept of a "headless-device", do a quick Google search.)

Comment: @ldg As always "real programmers do not read specs". In this case the question itself. "without X" means that the device has (probably) no graphic primitives/backend at all.  That phantom.js you have mentioned uses Qt and QtWebkit that may not work without graphics backend in principle. Yet pure terminal system may not have even basic scaleable fonts installed and so on.